# I'm trying to add custom route in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to add custom route in WordPress but it return "No route was found matching the URL and request method."

Here is my code
add_action('rest_api_init', 'university_search_route');

```
function university_search_route()
{
  register_rest_route('university/v1', 'search', array(
    'methods' => 'WP_REST_SERVER::READABLE',
    'callback' => 'universitySearchResults',
  ));
}

function universitySearchResults()
{
  return 'Hello';
}
```

What I'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: Have you tried changing WP_REST_SERVER::READABLE to GET to see if this is the issue?

Comment: Yes, This is the issue, Why WP_REST_SERVER::READABLE  isn't giving me appropriate result? Can you explain.

Comment: it might be the way its been spelt, try it with WP_REST_Server::READABLE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function university_search_route()
{
  register_rest_route('university/v1', 'search', array(
    'methods' => 'WP_REST_Server::READABLE', //probs the uppercase you had
    'callback' => 'universitySearchResults',
  ));
}

function universitySearchResults()
{
  return 'Hello';
}
```

Comment: can you tell me kow can I add more route like university/v1/more

Comment: register_rest_route('university/v1', 'more', array(
    'methods' => 'WP_REST_Server::READABLE',
    'callback' => 'another function name',
  ));